# Linux - How to zip files per subdirectory separately

Tags: linux, zip, archive

I have directory structure like this.

[image]

From this I want to create different zip files such as

data-A-A_1-A_11.zip

data-A-A_1-A_12.zip

data-B-B_1-B_11.zip

data-C-C_1-C_11.zip

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line;
do 
   echo "zip -r ${line//\//-}.zip $line";
   # zip -r "${line//\//-}.zip" "$line"
done <<< "$(find data -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 2 -type d)"
```

Redirect the result of a find command into a while loop. The find command searches the directory data for directories only, searching 3 directories deep only. In the while loop with use bash expansion to convert all forward slashes to "-" and add ".zip" in such a way that we can build a zip command on each directory. Once you are happy that the zip command looks fine when echoed for each directory, comment in the actual zip command